# Canasta: Going out without drawing

Tags: canasta

In Canasta, I go out without drawing a card for my final hand? I know I don’t have to discard, but do I need to draw a card?

Answer (score 1):

You are always required to draw a card to start your turn and that is the first thing you will do. When you are getting close to going out all you can do is hope that the card you draw will be playable.

[Canasta Game Rules](https://playingcarddecks.com/blogs/how-to-play/canasta-game-rules)

> The gameplay moves clockwise from the dealer. At the beginning of
> their turn they must take a card from either the stock or the discard
> pile. To take a card from the discard pile, the top card must either
> help begin a meld or build upon one already made. If you take from the
> discard pile, you must take all of the cards in the discard pile. At
> the end of your turn, you must discard one card.